# How scrap a div only when it contains a certain text- SELENIUM Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to automate LinkedIn and want to scrap the profile URL only if they are already not in a pending state.

```
<li class="reusable-search__result-container ">
          
                    
    <div class="entity-result" data-chameleon-result-urn="#">
  
  <div class="entity-result__item">
<div class="entity-result__universal-image">
<div class="display-flex align-items-center">
<!---->        
      <a class="app-aware-link scale-down " aria-hidden="true" href="#">
<div class="ivm-image-view-model   ">
<div class="ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper--use-img-tag display-flex

">
<!---->        
<div class="presence-entity presence-entity--size-3">
<img src="#" loading="lazy" alt="Grigorij Aronov" id="ember35" class="presence-entity__image  ivm-view-attr__img--centered EntityPhoto-circle-3  EntityPhoto-circle-3 lazy-image ember-view">


<div class="presence-entity__indicator

presence-entity__indicator--size-3 presence-indicator
hidden
presence-indicator--size-3">
<span class="visually-hidden">
Status is offline
</span>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</a>
    
</div>
</div>
<div class="entity-result__content entity-result__divider pt3 pb3 t-12 t-black--light">
<div class="mb1">

<div class="t-roman t-sans">

      
      <div class="display-flex">
<span class="entity-result__title-line entity-result__title-line--2-lines">
<span class="entity-result__title-text t-16">
<a class="app-aware-link" href="#">
  <span dir="ltr"><span aria-hidden="true"><!----><!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!----><!----></span></span>
</a>
  <span class="entity-result__badge t-14 t-normal t-black--light">
    <div class="display-flex
flex-row-reverse
align-items-baseline">
<div class="ivm-image-view-model    flex-shrink-zero align-self-center mr2 entity-result__badge-icon ml1">
<div class="ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper--use-img-tag display-flex

">
<li-icon type="linkedin-bug" size="14dp" color="premium" role="img" aria-label="Premium member"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 14 14" data-supported-dps="14x14" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="14" height="14" focusable="false">
<g>
<path class="background-mercado" d="M14 1v12a1 1 0 01-1 1H1a1 1 0 01-1-1V1a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 011 1zM4 5H2v7h2zm.25-2A1.27 1.27 0 003 1.8 1.27 1.27 0 001.75 3 1.27 1.27 0 003 4.2 1.27 1.27 0 004.25 3zM12 8.29c0-2.2-.73-3.49-2.86-3.49A2.71 2.71 0 006.89 6V5H5v7h2V8.73A1.74 1.74 0 018.66 6.8C9.82 6.8 10 7.94 10 8.73V12h2z"></path>
</g>
</svg></li-icon>
</div>
</div>
<span class="image-text-lockup__text entity-result__badge-text">
<span aria-hidden="true"><!---->• 2nd<!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!---->2nd degree connection<!----></span>
</span>
</div>
  </span>
</span>
</span>
<span aria-hidden="true" class="entity-result__badge-overflow align-self-flex-end t-14 t-normal t-black--light flex-shrink-zero
  ">
<div class="display-flex
flex-row-reverse
align-items-baseline">
<div class="ivm-image-view-model    flex-shrink-zero align-self-center mr2 entity-result__badge-icon ml1">
<div class="ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper--use-img-tag display-flex

">
<li-icon type="linkedin-bug" size="14dp" color="premium" role="img" aria-label="Premium member"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 14 14" data-supported-dps="14x14" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="14" height="14" focusable="false">
<g>
<path class="background-mercado" d="M14 1v12a1 1 0 01-1 1H1a1 1 0 01-1-1V1a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 011 1zM4 5H2v7h2zm.25-2A1.27 1.27 0 003 1.8 1.27 1.27 0 001.75 3 1.27 1.27 0 003 4.2 1.27 1.27 0 004.25 3zM12 8.29c0-2.2-.73-3.49-2.86-3.49A2.71 2.71 0 006.89 6V5H5v7h2V8.73A1.74 1.74 0 018.66 6.8C9.82 6.8 10 7.94 10 8.73V12h2z"></path>
</g>
</svg></li-icon>
</div>
</div>
<span class="image-text-lockup__text entity-result__badge-text">
<span aria-hidden="true"><!---->• 2nd<!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!---->2nd degree connection<!----></span>
</span>
</div>
</span>
</div>
    
  
</div>

<div class="linked-area flex-1
cursor-pointer">


<div>
<div class="entity-result__primary-subtitle t-14 t-black t-normal">
  <!----><!---->
</div>
  <div class="entity-result__secondary-subtitle t-14 t-normal">
    <!----><!---->
  </div>
</div>




</div>

</div>

<div class="linked-area flex-1
cursor-pointer">



</div>

<div class="entity-result__insights t-12">
  
        
            <div class="entity-result__simple-insight ">

  <div class="ivm-image-view-model    entity-result__simple-insight-image flex-shrink-zero mr2">
<div class="ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper--use-img-tag display-flex

">
<li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="people" size="small"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" data-supported-dps="16x16" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="16" height="16" focusable="false">
<path d="M14 11.75V15H9v-3.25A1.75 1.75 0 0110.75 10h1.5A1.75 1.75 0 0114 11.75zM11.5 9A2.5 2.5 0 109 6.5 2.5 2.5 0 0011.5 9zM5 1a3 3 0 103 3 3 3 0 00-3-3zm.75 7h-1.5A2.25 2.25 0 002 10.25V15h6v-4.75A2.25 2.25 0 005.75 8z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
</div>
</div>
<div class="entity-result__simple-insight-text-container">
  <span class="entity-result__simple-insight-text
      entity-result__simple-insight-text--small">

  </span>
<!---->      </div>

</div>

<!---->
<!---->
      
    
</div>
</div>
<div class="entity-result__actions entity-result__divider">
<!---->      
        
<div>
        
<button aria-label="Withdraw invitation sent to Grigorij Aronov" id="ember57" class="artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--full artdeco-button--secondary ember-view" type="button"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
Pending
</span></button>


<!---->

<!---->
<!---->

</div>

    
</div>
</div>


</div>

<!---->                  
  </li>


<li class="reusable-search__result-container ">
          
                    
    <div class="entity-result" data-chameleon-result-urn="#">
  
  <div class="entity-result__item">
<div class="entity-result__universal-image">
<div class="display-flex align-items-center">
<!---->        
      <a class="app-aware-link scale-down " aria-hidden="true" href="#">
<div class="ivm-image-view-model   ">
<div class="ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper--use-img-tag display-flex">
<!---->        
<div class="presence-entity presence-entity--size-3">
<img src="#">


<div class="presence-entity__indicatorpresence-entity__indicator--size-3 presence-indicatorhiddenpresence-indicator--size-3">
<span class="visually-hidden">
Status is offline
</span>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</a>
    
</div>
</div>
<div class="entity-result__content entity-result__divider pt3 pb3 t-12 t-black--light">
<div class="mb1">

<div class="t-roman t-sans">

      
      <div class="display-flex">
<span class="entity-result__title-line entity-result__title-line--2-lines">
<span class="entity-result__title-text t-16">

  <span class="entity-result__badge t-14 t-normal t-black--light">
    <div class="display-flex
flex-row-reverse
align-items-baseline">
<!---->    <span class="image-text-lockup__text entity-result__badge-text">
<span aria-hidden="true"><!---->• 2nd<!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!---->2nd degree connection<!----></span>
</span>
</div>
  </span>
</span>
</span>
<span aria-hidden="true" class="entity-result__badge-overflow align-self-flex-end t-14 t-normal t-black--light flex-shrink-zero
  ">
<div class="display-flex
flex-row-reverse
align-items-baseline">
<!---->    <span class="image-text-lockup__text entity-result__badge-text">
<span aria-hidden="true"><!---->• 2nd<!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!---->2nd degree connection<!----></span>
</span>
</div>
</span>
</div>
    
  
</div>

<div class="linked-area flex-1
cursor-pointer">


<div>
<div class="entity-result__primary-subtitle t-14 t-black t-normal">
  <!---->#<!---->
</div>
  <div class="entity-result__secondary-subtitle t-14 t-normal">
    <!---->#<!---->
  </div>
</div>




</div>

</div>

<div class="linked-area flex-1
cursor-pointer">

  

</div>

<div class="entity-result__insights t-12">
  
        
            <div class="entity-result__simple-insight ">

  <div class="ivm-image-view-model    entity-result__simple-insight-image flex-shrink-zero mr2">
<div class="ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper ivm-view-attr__img-wrapper--use-img-tag display-flex

">
<li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="people" size="small"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" data-supported-dps="16x16" fill="currentColor" class="mercado-match" width="16" height="16" focusable="false">
<path d="M14 11.75V15H9v-3.25A1.75 1.75 0 0110.75 10h1.5A1.75 1.75 0 0114 11.75zM11.5 9A2.5 2.5 0 109 6.5 2.5 2.5 0 0011.5 9zM5 1a3 3 0 103 3 3 3 0 00-3-3zm.75 7h-1.5A2.25 2.25 0 002 10.25V15h6v-4.75A2.25 2.25 0 005.75 8z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>
</div>
</div>


</div>

<!---->
<!---->
      
    
</div>
</div>
<div class="entity-result__actions entity-result__divider">
<!---->      
        
<div>
        <button aria-label="Invite Lucas Teuchner to connect" id="ember55" class="artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--secondary ember-view"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">Connect</span></button>

<!---->
<!---->

</div>

    
</div>
</div>


</div>

<!---->                  
  </li>
```

There are 2 blocks of HTML. One contains a button with "Pending" and the other with "Connect". I want to scrap the profile URL of the one inside "Connect" li.

If you find this question stupid, I'm sorry. I'm not advanced in Selenium.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is absolutely fine, @Gaurav. Thing is, what are you trying to do? Click a button? Scrape some part of the page you did not include in your HTML?

Comment: I want to scrap the profile address. <a class="app-aware-link scale-down " aria-hidden="true" href="#"> Url present in this tag.

Comment: Did it solve your issue? @Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to locate that element with the following (if element is not in an iframe, shadow root, or some other unforeseen elements in that page):

```
profile_link = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text() = 'Connect']/ancestor::li//a[@class = 'app-aware-link']")))
```

You will also need to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: True, corrected now... likely because it was preceded with an 'a'.